# Nginx vs Cherokee replacement for Apache

Tags: apache, nginx, cherokee

How do you compare Nginx and Cherokee in terms of memory usage and performance?  My VPS serves Drupal 6.16, magento 1.4.1 and CS-CART 2.0.15 with apache2 prefork-mpm. Apache2 eats my memory even though my sites are pretty low traffic profile (htop shows that each apache process eats %18 memory) . If I change apache to nginx or cherokee will I face any compatibility issues with magento, cs-cart and drupal? Which one is the most compatible with? I reallly appreciate any production system experience.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can greatly reduce the memory consumption of your VPS by installing a PHP accelerator such a [eAccelerator](http://eaccelerator.net/). In most cases Apache web server will perform just fine. You might need to tweak it to optimize for your specific set up. You need to do some reading up on that though, since there is no silver bullet when it comes to that.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the post below for some memory related measurements for Apache, Cherokee and Nginx.  You might google around for similar results.  However, I would recommend running such tests with typical cases in mind to see how it fits your use case.

- [Benchmark of django deployment techniques](http://brainacle.com/benchmark-of-django-deployment-techniques.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try Hiawatha: http://www.hiawatha-webserver.org/. Its UrlToolkit is far more advanced than Apache's mod_rewrite. Yes, the frameworks you mentioned will run fine with Hiawatha. Tested it myself.